# Haskell similar types copy-paste elimination in case

Tags: haskell, coding-style

```
case x of 
  Cond expr stmt -> do
        checkExprType expr Bool
        processStmt env stmt
        return env
  AnotherCond expr stmt -> do
        checkExprType expr Bool
        processStmt env stmt
        return env
```

How can this copy-paste be eliminated?

Comment: A bit more detail will be more helpful.  However, I think two different value constructor having a very similar structure might let you merge them into one.

Comment: you should give more details !

Comment: What's unclear about that question? Two blocks that look the same but different name of type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just make a local definition which is a function of `expr` and `stmt`:

```
-- I assume this is all inside a 'do' block
let conditionalLike expr stmt = do
        checkExprType expr Bool
        processStmt env stmt
        return env
case x of
    Cond expr stmt -> conditionalLike expr stmt
    AnotherCond expr stmt -> conditionalLike expr stmt
```